# ASP.NET Master Page Server Control Events

Tags: asp.net, event-handling, master-pages

I had been having a great deal of issues trying to put a server control button and event handler onto a master page. Every time I clicked the button from one of the content pages, the postback would take me not back to the content page, but to the site.master URL, so naturally that would crash my application. I scoured the internet for a solution, but I couldn't get any to work for me. I finally figured out a very easy fix and so I thought I'd share it in case anyone else runs into similar troubles.

Answer (score 0):

On the Master Page's Page_Init() method, I assigned the PostBackUrl attribute of the server control to the current page Uri using HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
(UserLogin is my button control name)

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserLogin.PostBackUrl = HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsoluteUri;
}
```